# How to get mouse double click event from the title of QGroupBox?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2

I have a QGroupBox and wanted to do some action when I double-click it.
However, I want to restrict the interaction area to only the title of QGroupBox, not his body or the widget inside it.

Found a C++ solution here - https://forum.qt.io/topic/131379/how-to-get-mouse-double-click-event-from-only-the-title-of-qgroupbox/2

How can we do this in Python?

Comment: The code in the linked post clearly shows how to implement that. Porting it to python is not that difficult, it's just a matter of understanding what it does: calling the base class implementation, creating a QStyleOptionGroupBox instance, initialize it and verify if the event `pos()` is within what the `hitTestComplexControl` would return. Did you try to implement that? If so, please provide a proper [mre].

Comment: See [ask]. You need to implement a prototype and do a preliminary debugging. SO is not a free coding service.